# Non-intuitive output from dmvnorm() within R mvtnorm package

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I am trying dmvnorm() in the R package of mvtnorm with very similar matrices and resultant density are very different.  More specifically,

```
library(mvtnorm)

library(magrittr)

train_mat2 <- 
  data.frame(c1 = c(13.29, 13.68, 14.06, 14.10, 13.86, 13.05, 14.20, 13.77, 
                    12.64, 13.67, 12.17, 12.37, 12.37, 12.29, 13.86, 13.49,
                    11.66, 11.84, 12.33, 12.70, 12.00),
             c2 = c(2.68, 2.36, 2.61, 2.40, 2.27, 2.55, 2.45, 2.68, 2.02, 1.92, 
                    2.53, 2.56, 1.92, 2.21, 2.67, 2.24, 1.92, 2.23, 1.95, 2.40, 2.00)) %>%
  as.matrix()

train_mat3 <- train_mat2[1:20,]


dmvnorm(train_mat2,
        mean=colMeans(train_mat2),
        sigma=cov(train_mat2))

dmvnorm(train_mat3,
        mean=colMeans(train_mat3),
        sigma=cov(train_mat3))
```

The first dmvnorm output

```
         mean=colMeans(train_mat2),
         sigma=cov(train_mat2))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`
```

while the second dmvnorm output

```
         mean=colMeans(train_mat3),
         sigma=cov(train_mat3))
 [1] 0.32385982 0.59184100 0.33153870 0.34550971 0.38847115 0.52154257 0.30568408 0.32928314 0.41859960 0.07385217 0.16868584 0.21340448 0.25124098
[14] 0.51129759 0.32758244 0.58043723 0.12999843 0.24604814 0.28729287 0.63333639
```

Given the two matrices differ by one row, I am not sure I understand why dmvnorm() function output dramatically different results.  Could you please help me understand it?

Thanks!

I am expecting the first dmvnorm() output something similar to the output of the second dmvnorm() call.

Here is a screenshot of the result after I reran it in a new RStudio Session.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: could you try again, I cannot reproduce your issue

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for helping me to edit my post. I appreciate your help.  I have just uploaded a screenshot of the result on my computer.  Thanks.

Comment: The issue must be with your computer. You will have to restart R. Just copy pasted your code and I do not get 0's

Comment: @Onyambu Thank you for your feedback.  I agree with you this has to do with my computer.  I still cannot figure it out why, though.  Luckily, I found another library mvnfast with dmvn() that seems to work.  Thank you again!